# How to use windows authentication without username/password

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I have publish my first website on iis 8, when I right click on it and browse I am able to access it. When I enter my ip in chrome or IE I am prompt for my username and password.
Windows authentication is set to true and anonymous is set to false, my web.config looks like that :

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <authorization>      
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I don't want my users to enter their creds but I want to be able to have their windows username at the top of the page. Is there something I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're intent on using windows authentication but don't want users to have to enter their credentials you'll have to limit users to using IE and you'll have to ensure that the address of the website is identified as an intranet site - only then will IE automatically send the current user's windows credentials when challenged.  To my knowledge none of the other browsers support this on the windows platform (there might be plugins though).

[This knowledge-base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174360) might be of use - in short you can make sure that the address(es) of your site are added to your users intranet zone and then credentials will automatically be supplied.

If this is an AD environment, you can get the domain admins to add the addresses to group policy to roll this out for all users.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an intranet web app?

Check out this article and see if it helps:
[ALL Operations on Active Directory (AD) using c#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/all-operations-on-active-directory-ad-using-C-Sharp/)

Otherwise consider using a Membership provider (but indeed you would need the users to log in at least the very first time, depending on how you set it up)

I believe once you require Windows Auth in your web config, you will need to authorize via un and pw.  So try it with anonymous login and some of the methods described in the article.  When it's set at Windows Auth, that only pertains to the AD on the server, not necessarily a client machine.

Comment: With anonymous I am not asked for my creds. It is an intranet app so it is not suppose to ask me for my creds

Comment: That's good right?  It sounded like that was what you were after.  If this is a web app, I don't think it's possible.  If it is a Windows app, maybe, but I would leave that for someone else to answer.  Because of the security risk, browsers won't reveal the username of the client machine.  If the website is hosted on, or has access to the same Active Directory that the clients user to login on everyday, then the above link may be helpful.  Otherwise, seriously consider a membership provider solution in conjunction with a database (SQL + ASPNET Membership comes to mind).